# How to set `ubuntu` vm box screen resolution to `1600x900`

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, resolution

I am running a virtual box ( version 4.1.8 ) on my windows 10, but my virtual box having the maximum screen resolution as `1027x768` But my computer resolution is `1600x900` how to I update my virutal box ( ubuntu ) screen to get my monitor resolution?

I tried this :

`xrandr --addmode VGA1 1600x900` But I came up with error as :

```
dev@ubuntu14044:~$ xrandr --addmode VGA1 1600x900
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "VGA1"
dev@ubuntu14044:~$
```

how to fix this? or what is the correct way to set the required screen resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a newbie, before doing anything else with a fresh VM...

Start your VM and then select "Menu:Devices>Insert Guest additions CD"
Let it install - there should be a display driver in there...
(Remember: In a VM, **Virtualbox** *is* your hardware)

As that has been done, visit
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
and check for the latest suitable "VirtualBox Extension Pack" and get that downloaded and installed (allows use of USB among other things).

With that done, read up on documentation and you're set for a nice experience.

Comment: when I try, I am getting this error : `Unable to insert the virtual optical disk C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the machine Ubuntu14044.



Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
Callee: IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}

`

Comment: That looks as a Windows-related error, I do not "do" Windows any longer.